# ng2-charts - Angular 4 working example

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to use ng2-charts with Angular 4.0 and I would like to have the same thing like here by using chart.js:

```
    ...
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    ...

    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            // The type of chart we want to create
            type: 'horizontalBar',

            // The data for our dataset
            data: {
                labels: ["example1","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6","example7"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                },{
                    label: "My second dataset",
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(2, 99, 132)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    data: [3, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
                }]
            },

            // Configuration options go here
            options: {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

What I have done is

```
npm install ng2-charts --save
npm install chart.js --save
```

and I have added

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>
```

to src/index.html

and

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';

imports: [
   ChartsModule
]
```

to src/app/app.module.ts

Can you show me an working example of src/index.html, src/app/app.component.html and app/component.ts for it? Because I have some problems with it like in example

```
GET 
http://localhost:4200/node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 8 ms]
ERROR Error: "undefined" is not a chart type.
```

even if I change the chart.js location.

src/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chart</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/src/chart.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

src/app/app.component.html

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>

    <div style="display: block">
      <canvas baseChart
              [data]="chartData"
              (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button (click)="randomize()">Update</button>
```

src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  public chartData: Array<any> = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];

}
```

Comment: Try adding `chartType="horizontalBar"` to `<canvas baseChart`

Comment: I can see something now, instead of white page, thanks! But I still have a problem with GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1 ms]

Comment: If you have `chart.js` installed as a dependency, you could get the bundle from the URL @EA_ gave you. Otherwise, from `node_modules/ng2-chart/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your chart.js 
to

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**app module ts code**

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

// In your App's module:
imports: [
   ChartsModule
]
```

**Update** 
remove script tag in index.html and add in

check your **angular-cli.json** and **scripts** array, then inside it add:

**"../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"**

Comment: GET 
http://localhost:4200/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1 ms]
ERROR Error: "undefined" is not a chart type.

Comment: you don't need to include the js file via a script tag.  The inclusion in app.module.ts is enough. `import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';`

Comment: how i can add this package in angular-quickstart, it shows patch issue in systemJs file

Comment: i agree with shaheen. maybe the answer is older. using cli 1.4.3 and ng2-charts 1.6.0 i installed ng2-charts via npm and imported the charts module into my app module `import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'; imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      FormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      ChartsModule 
  ]` and i was able to get a chart in my component without adding the scripts to .angular-cli.json. I actually get some kind of error in the console when i add the script to .angular-cli.json.

Answer (score 1):

Aside adding the `chart.js` file to `.angular-cli.json`, you're only missing the `chartType` passed as an input to `baseChart`.

```
<canvas baseChart
        [chartType]="'horizontalBar'"
        [data]="chartData"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

// In your App's module:
imports: [
   ChartsModule
]